# Syntax Error in previously working CSS Style Sheet

Tags: css, stylesheet, squarespace

I'm migrating from Squarespace 5 to Squarespace 6, and part of that process is bringing over the style sheet from the previous site.  The style sheet has worked without problems for years, but now after copying it: I receive a syntax error message for this line, which is copied below:

```
/* corrects horizontal menu width */
.horizontalNavigationBar {width:$(CanvasWidth-ContentPaddingExternal-ContentPaddingExternal)$; }
```

Can anyone offer guidance on what is wrong here?

Comment: That isn't valid CSS.

Comment: @SLaks It is Squarespace stuff.

Comment: have you posted to http://answers.squarespace.com/?

Comment: I haven't and I didn't realize the difference.  Thank you for the guidance, I will do that.